# Can we use classic load balancer ARN to register instances through CLI

Tags: amazon-elb

CLI command to register instances to a classic load balancer is:

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name my-load-balancer --instances i-d6f6fae3
```

Can we use classic ELB's ARN in --load-balancer-name parameter? If yes, how do we get the classic ELB's ARN and does the command change in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use ELB's ARN in `--load-balancer-name` parameter. ARNs are usually long strings, mostly exceeding 32 characters. `--load-balancer-name` accepts only strings <32 characters. That's one way to find out ARNs cannot be used for that parameter.